# Calculating pandas column until the end

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pandas.set_option('display.width', None)
df1 = pandas.read_json("""{"A":{"1062374400000":0.004270709,"1064966400000":0.010686493,"1067644800000":0.006375888,"1070236800000":0.006175395,"1072915200000":0.007879588,"1075593600000":0.01078674,"1078099200000":0.006375888,"1080777600000":0.008180328,"1083369600000":0.006576382,"1086048000000":0.006476135},"B":{"1062374400000":0.0590058044,"1064966400000":0.4393213977,"1067644800000":0.4708762019,"1070236800000":0.6544813354,"1072915200000":1.154254136,"1075593600000":null,"1078099200000":null,"1080777600000":null,"1083369600000":null,"1086048000000":null},"C":{"1062374400000":-0.0309941956,"1064966400000":0.1993213977,"1067644800000":0.0508762019,"1070236800000":0.2044813354,"1072915200000":0.514254136,"1075593600000":null,"1078099200000":null,"1080777600000":null,"1083369600000":null,"1086048000000":null},"D":{"1062374400000":null,"1064966400000":null,"1067644800000":null,"1070236800000":null,"1072915200000":null,"1075593600000":null,"1078099200000":null,"1080777600000":null,"1083369600000":null,"1086048000000":null},"E":{"1062374400000":null,"1064966400000":null,"1067644800000":null,"1070236800000":null,"1072915200000":null,"1075593600000":null,"1078099200000":null,"1080777600000":null,"1083369600000":null,"1086048000000":null}}
""")
print(df1)
```

I have the above algo, which translates into the following DF:

```
                   A         B         C   D   E
2003-09-01  0.004271  0.059006 -0.030994 NaN NaN
2003-10-01  0.010686  0.439321  0.199321 NaN NaN
2003-11-01  0.006376  0.470876  0.050876 NaN NaN
2003-12-01  0.006175  0.654481  0.204481 NaN NaN
2004-01-01  0.007880  1.154254  0.514254 NaN NaN
2004-02-01  0.010787       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
2004-03-01  0.006376       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
2004-04-01  0.008180       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
2004-05-01  0.006576       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
2004-06-01  0.006476       NaN       NaN NaN NaN
```

I'm trying to use the following math to calculate D and E values:

`Dn = E(n-1) * An`

`En = E(n-1) + Cn + Dn` or `En = E(n-1) + Cn + (E(n-1) * An)`

For the equation to work, the first value of E should be manually set. `E[0]` = `C[0]`.

I'm using the following algorithm:

```
df1['E'].iloc[0] = df1['C'].iloc[0] # Giving E[0] it's first value (C[0])
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    df1['D'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] * df1['A'].iloc[i]
    df1['E'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] + df1['C'].iloc[i] + df1['D'].iloc[i]
```

However, the result is calculating only few rows of D and E.

I thought it could be because somewhen there will be no C or D to calculate E, so I also tried this algo:

```
df1['E'].iloc[0] = df1['C'].iloc[0] # Giving E[0] it's first value (C[0])
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    df1['D'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] * df1['A'].iloc[i]
    if df1['C'].iloc[i] == numpy.nan:
        df1['C'].iloc[i] = 0
    if df1['D'].iloc[i] == numpy.nan:
        df1['D'].iloc[i] = 0
    df1['E'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] + df1['C'].iloc[i] + df1['D'].iloc[i]
```

However, the result is still the same:

```
                   A         B         C         D         E
2003-09-01  0.004271  0.059006 -0.030994       NaN -0.030994
2003-10-01  0.010686  0.439321  0.199321 -0.000331  0.167996
2003-11-01  0.006376  0.470876  0.050876  0.001071  0.219943
2003-12-01  0.006175  0.654481  0.204481  0.001358  0.425783
2004-01-01  0.007880  1.154254  0.514254  0.003355  0.943392
2004-02-01  0.010787       NaN       NaN  0.010176       NaN
2004-03-01  0.006376       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2004-04-01  0.008180       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2004-05-01  0.006576       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2004-06-01  0.006476       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

What do I need to make sure D and E are calculated untill the end of the DF?

Expected results (asked in comments):

```
                    A         B          C            D          E
2003-09-01 0,00427071 0,0590058 -0,0309942          NaN -0,0309942
2003-10-01  0,0106865  0,439321   0,199321 -0,000331219   0,167996
2003-11-01 0,00637589  0,470876  0,0508762   0,00107112   0,219943
2003-12-01  0,0061754  0,654481   0,204481   0,00135824   0,425783
2004-01-01 0,00787959   1,15425   0,514254   0,00335499   0,943392
2004-02-01  0,0107867       NaN          0    0,0101761   0,953568
2004-03-01 0,00637589       NaN          0   0,00607984   0,959648
2004-04-01 0,00818033       NaN          0   0,00785024   0,967498
2004-05-01 0,00657638       NaN          0   0,00636264   0,973861
2004-06-01 0,00647614       NaN          0   0,00630685   0,980168
```

Comment: What would your ideal result look like?

Comment: Well, for Dn, it'd be multiplying E(n-1) until the end. For En, it'd be adding E(n-1), Cn and Dn until the end. However, at some point, there will be no C to add (c = 0).

Comment: Right. Would you mind updating your question to show what the frame would look like? It's helpful to have something to compare solutions to make sure the correct results are being obtained.

Comment: Okay. Wait a minute.

Comment: @HenryEcker Question updated.

Comment: @el_oso it's already there, at the top of the question.

Comment: I don't quite understand the cyclic definition. You need D to calculate E, but you need E to calculate D.

Comment: sorry, missied it :)

Comment: @HenryEcker Mathematically, calculating the first value of D is impossible (should be 0 or error, as you're multiplying by something that is not defined E[-1]), so, it should be NaN. Everything else is possible, as you have the first value of E manually stated (C[0])

Answer (score 2):

maybe slightly cleaner using `fillna()` to set all your `NaN` values to `0` so you don't have to worry about them in the loop. Should be a little bit faster

```
df1.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df1['E'].iloc[0] = df1['C'].iloc[0] # Giving E[0] it's first value (C[0])
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    df1['D'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] * df1['A'].iloc[i]
    df1['E'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] + df1['C'].iloc[i] + df1['D'].iloc[i]

            A           B           C           D           E
2003-09-01  0.004271    0.059006    -0.030994   0.000000    -0.030994
2003-10-01  0.010686    0.439321    0.199321    -0.000331   0.167996
2003-11-01  0.006376    0.470876    0.050876    0.001071    0.219943
2003-12-01  0.006175    0.654481    0.204481    0.001358    0.425783
2004-01-01  0.007880    1.154254    0.514254    0.003355    0.943392
2004-02-01  0.010787    0.000000    0.000000    0.010176    0.953568
2004-03-01  0.006376    0.000000    0.000000    0.006080    0.959648
2004-04-01  0.008180    0.000000    0.000000    0.007850    0.967498
2004-05-01  0.006576    0.000000    0.000000    0.006363    0.973861
2004-06-01  0.006476    0.000000    0.000000    0.006307    0.980168
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the following algorithm to make the calcules:

```
df1['E'].iloc[0] = df1['C'].iloc[0] # Giving E[0] it's first value (C[0])
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    df1['D'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] * df1['A'].iloc[i]
    if df1['C'].iloc[i] == numpy.nan:
        df1['C'].iloc[i] = 0
    if df1['D'].iloc[i] == numpy.nan:
        df1['D'].iloc[i] = 0
    df1['E'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] + df1['C'].iloc[i] + df1['D'].iloc[i]
```

However, what apparently had to be done was:

```
df1['E'].iloc[0] = df1['C'].iloc[0]
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    df1['D'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] * df1['A'].iloc[i]
    if numpy.isnan(df1['C'].iloc[i]):
        df1['C'].iloc[i] = 0
    if numpy.isnan(df1['D'].iloc[i]):
        df1['D'].iloc[i] = 0
    df1['E'].iloc[i] = df1['E'].iloc[i - 1] + df1['C'].iloc[i] + df1['D'].iloc[i]
```

People let me know if someone has a better solution. For now, this is working.